# How can get value "Id" row in DataGrid using event MouseDoubleClick?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, datagrid

I have DataGrid this DataGrid content some row and columns "Id ...",  but i don't know how can get value column "Id" when user double click by mouse.

This code for MouseDoubleClick:

```
 <DataGrid ... >
        <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="Row_DoubleClick"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        ...
 </DataGrid>
```

> Behind code:

```
  private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("here I want get column id when user DoubleClick some row");
  }
```

Comment: This might help you: http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html

Comment: thank you very much, can you write answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you further:
[WPF DataGrid - detecting the column, cell and row that has been clicked](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html)

Answer (score 2):

This will also work

```
private void Row_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    int index = DataGridName.SelectedIndex;
    MessageBox.Show(index);
  }
```

Hope that answers your question. :)